# Template class specialization for multiple types satisfying a condition

Tags: c++, template-specialization

If I have a template class, like so:

```
template<typename T>
class Type { /* ... */ };
```

Without modifying `Type` in any way, is there a simple way to specialize it for *all* such types that match a compile-time condition? For example, if I wanted to specialize `Type` for all integral types, I'd like to do something like this (only something that works, that is):

```
template<typename T>
class Type<std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>, T>::type> { /* ... */ };
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
template<typename T, bool B = std::is_integral<T>::value>
class Type;

// doesn't have to be a specialization, although I think it's more clear this way
template<typename T>
class Type<T, false> { /* ... */ };

template<typename T>
class Type<T, true> { /* ... */ };
```

Comment: "*Without modifying `Type` in any way*" -- this doesn't qualify.

Comment: Close enough (I can see multiple reasons for why the idea I sought is unfeasible for compiler writers, or, indeed, standard authors.)

Comment: Maybe Type was modified, but from the point of view of the rest of the code it looks pretty much the same.